# Jackson - deserialize using Builder without annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

Is it possible to use Jackson to deserialize a value class (final, no setters) that only has an all args constructor and a Builder? I can't use the `JsonDeserialize` and `JsonPOJOBuilder` since I am trying to deserialize a model defined in a client library, so I cannot add the annotations. Can I specify the builder to use another way?

Comment: Just implement your own `JsonDeserializer`

Comment: @rkosegi I'm guessing there isn't an easier way to do that without basically enumerating all the field names and invoking the builder manually?

Comment: do you have multiple types of objects that needs to be deserialized or just one?

Comment: I have 3 different types I need to deserialize

Comment: Then either create 3 different JsonDeserializer implementations or employ more robust approach with reflection.

Comment: If your model contains multiple attributes like attributes you want to serialize and attributes you don't need to serialize then JsonDeserialize with JsonIgnore would be good option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using MixIn.

I have created one sample for your use case:

Original class:

```
final class Sample {

    final int id;

    Sample(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

MixIn (provide non-args constructor with same args):

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
abstract class SampleMixin {
    @JsonCreator
    public SampleMixin(@JsonProperty("id") int id) {
    }
}
```

Deserilaization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(Sample.class, SampleMixin.class);
Sample sample = mapper.readValue(json, Sample.class);
```

Comment: I actually took it a step further and used a ```@JsonDeserialize(builder = ...)``` on a MixIn and it worked! That way I don't have to map out all the fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can. Builder must meet certain requirements. For instance its methods for fields must have certain prefix, like "with" or "set".

Here is DTO class and its builder without any jackson annotations:

```
public class DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson {

  public final String stringValue;

  private DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson(final String stringValue){
    this.stringValue = stringValue;
  }

  public static Builder builder(){
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static class Builder {
    private String stringValue;

    public Builder withStringValue(String stringValue) {
      this.stringValue = stringValue;
      return this;
    }
    public DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson build() {
      return new DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson(stringValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Without any additional effort with a default custom object you can serialize this dto object. You are responsible for instance creation. Jackson only needs to access fields. In our case this is a public field.

In case DTO is used for deserialization, you need to customize custom object:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector(){
  @Override
  public Class<?> findPOJOBuilder(AnnotatedClass ac) {
    //set analogue of: @JsonDeserialize(builder = DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson.Builder.class)
    if (DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson.class.equals(ac.getRawType())) {
      return DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson.Builder.class;
    } else {
      return super.findPOJOBuilder(ac);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public JsonPOJOBuilder.Value findPOJOBuilderConfig(AnnotatedClass ac) {
    if (DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson.class.equals(ac.getRawType())) {
      //both build and with - are default in this case:
      //set analogue of @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "with")
      return new JsonPOJOBuilder.Value("build", "with");
    } else {
      return super.findPOJOBuilderConfig(ac);
    }
  }
});
```

and use this customized CustomObject in your implementations. Here is a test and full example can be found here: [DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJackson test](https://github.com/AlexandrSokolov/jax_rs/blob/master/jax_rs_resteasy_api/src/test/java/com/savdev/jax/rs/resteasy/dto/without/jackson/DtoBuilderWithFinalFieldsWithoutJacksonTest.java)