# jackson deserialize json to object without annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have old Pojos inside jar.   Example;

```
   public class human implements Serializable {
   }

   public class Man extend human {
  } 

  public class Woman extend human {
  }
```

I have json like {"type":"man",...}

I want to deserialize proper class using type But I cannot use these annotations because Base class generated automatically from xsd.

> @JsonTypeInfo(//      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, //      include =
> JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, //         property = "queryType", //
> visible = true) @JsonSubTypes({ //      @Type(value =
> ScenarioByCountryQuery.class, name = "scenarioByCountry"), //
> @Type(value = ScenarioByMeasureQuery.class, name =
> "scenarioByMeasure")  })

I don want to desearlize like if type = '' etc.
I want to deserialize dynamically using this type value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson - deserialize using Builder without annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903678/jackson-deserialize-using-builder-without-annotation)

Comment: thank you but this is not my question answer

Comment: Try to use `MixIn` feature. Some examples: [MixIn method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255539/51591), [MixIn class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600499/51591)